# How to create an sql code automatically based on a json-schema file

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I have a JSON-Schema file like the following and i need to create tables in PostgreSQL based on it automatically.

Need your help

```
"$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "$defs": {
    "FC1": {
      "$anchor": "FC1",
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "../Th1/th1s.json"
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "properties": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "@type": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "Attr1": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "Attr2": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "attr3": {
                  "$ref": "#/$defs/Attr3Value"
                },
                "attr4": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "uri"
                  },
                  "uniqueItems": true
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "@type",
                "attr3"
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "properties"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    
    "FC2": {
      "$anchor": "FC2",
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "../FC21.json"
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "geometry": {
              "$ref": "https://geojson.org/schema/Point.json"
            },
            "properties": {
......
          },
          "required": [
            "properties"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

i tried many python scripts such as :

```
import json
from jsonschema2db import JSONSchemaToPostgres
import psycopg2

schema = json.load(open('jsonschema.json'))
print (schema)
translator = JSONSchemaToPostgres(
    schema,
    postgres_schema='s1',
    item_col_name='file_id',
    item_col_type='string',
    abbreviations={
        'AbbreviateThisReallyLongColumn': 'AbbTRLC',
    }
)

con = psycopg2.connect('host=myhostname dbname=db user=psqluser password= psqlpw')
translator.create_tables(con)

con.commit()
```

Comment: And what happened when you tied that?

Comment: That object has nested objects.  What exactly are you expecting the resulting table to look like?  Perhaps you should show us an example based on your subset.

Comment: Warning (from warnings module):
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jsonschema2db.py", line 146
    warnings.warn('%s.%s: Type info missing' % (table, self._column_name(path)))
UserWarning: root.: Type info missing

Comment: i expect to get an sql code to create an empty table based on this json schema!!

Comment: Maybe, but I don't think you have any idea what such a table would look like, and if you don't, how can you know whether it has been done correctly?  What would the columns in your table(s) be?  That particular structure does not map directly to a relational database.

Comment: Are you expecting FC1 to be a column, or a table?  If it is a column, what type is it?  If it is a table, what are the columns?  `attr3` doesn't have a type here.

Comment: FC1 : table 1; attr1: attribute 1 in FC1; FC2: Table 2, etc

Comment: FC: Feature Class

Comment: It's true that your outermost level is missing `"type": "object"`.  I believe that's the complaint.

Comment: i added it already... new error appears : AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jsonschema2db.py", line 174
    warnings.warn('%s.%s: Object with neither properties nor patternProperties' % (table, self._column_name(path)))
UserWarning: root.: Object with neither properties nor patternProperties

Comment: there is no simple method to convert the jsonschema file to an xml or xsd?

Comment: That would be an entirely separate question..  The problem here is your JSON schema does not meet the spec.